# Requests + Proxy Servers, IP address won't change

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, ip-address

I am using the python shell to test requests together with proxy servers.
After reading documentation (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) and a few stackoverflow threads I am doing the following:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
proxies = {'http': 'http://90.178.216.202:3128'}
s.proxies.update(proxies)
req = s.get('http://jsonip.com')
```

After this, if I print req.text, I get this:
u'{"ip":"my current IP (not the proxy server IP I have inserted before)","about":"/about", ......}'

Can you please explain why I'm getting my computer's IP address and not the proxy server's IP address?
Did I go wrong somewhere or am I expecting the wrong thing to happen here?
I am new to requests + proxy servers so I would like to make sure I am understanding this.

UPDATE
I also have this in my code:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0'}
s.headers.update(headers)
```

Thanks
Vittorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site ( *http://jsonip.com* ) broadcasts an 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' header. This means that your request gets redirected to **https**://jsonip.com, so `requests` doesn't use a proxy because you don't have an https proxy in your `proxies` dict.

So, all you have to do is add an https proxy in `proxies` , eg:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://90.178.216.202:3128', 'https':'https://90.178.216.202:3128'}
```

Comment: @pajarnas Why don't you post a question then? If you don't get any answers you can ping me and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this pass user-agent

requests.post(url='abc.com',header={'user-agent':'Mozila 5.0'})

Comment: I have updated my question to include this, I did not mentioned that before as I thought it was not important

Answer (score 0):

u need to change ur get request to have the proxies used.

something like this:`req = s.get('http://jsonip.com', proxies=proxies)`